# Bundle install gets permission issues with global RVM install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, bundle

So I have a global install of RVM on a machine that is on a school cluster that I have multiple users using for a school project. When I run a bundle install now however I get the following error:

```
bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
mv: cannot remove `/home/benjamin/.bundler/tmp/29173/cache/rake-10.1.0.gem': Permission denied
Using rake (10.1.0)
mv: cannot remove `/home/benjamin/.bundler/tmp/29173/cache/i18n-0.6.1.gem': Permission denied
Using i18n (0.6.1)
mv: cannot remove `/home/benjamin/.bundler/tmp/29173/cache/multi_json-1.7.7.gem': Permission denied
Installing multi_json (1.7.7)
mv: cannot remove `/home/benjamin/.bundler/tmp/29173/cache/activesupport-3.2.13.gem': Permission denied
Using activesupport (3.2.13)
mv: cannot remove `/home/benjamin/.bundler/tmp/29173/cache/builder-3.0.4.gem': Permission denied
Using builder (3.0.4)
mv: cannot remove `/home/benjamin/.bundler/tmp/29173/cache/activemodel-3.2.13.gem': Permission denied
Using activemodel (3.2.13)
mv: cannot remove `/home/benjamin/.bundler/tmp/29173/cache/erubis-2.7.0.gem': Permission denied
Using erubis (2.7.0)
mv: cannot remove `/home/benjamin/.bundler/tmp/29173/cache/journey-1.0.4.gem': Permission denied
Installing journey (1.0.4)
mv: cannot remove `/home/benjamin/.bundler/tmp/29173/cache/rack-1.4.5.gem': Permission denied
Installing rack (1.4.5)
mv: cannot remove `/home/benjamin/.bundler/tmp/29173/cache/rack-cache-1.2.gem': Permission denied
Installing rack-cache (1.2)
mv: cannot remove `/home/benjamin/.bundler/tmp/29173/cache/rack-test-0.6.2.gem': Permission denied
Installing rack-test (0.6.2)
mv: cannot remove `/home/benjamin/.bundler/tmp/29173/cache/hike-1.2.3.gem': Permission denied
Installing hike (1.2.3)
mv: cannot remove `/home/benjamin/.bundler/tmp/29173/cache/tilt-1.4.1.gem': Permission denied
Installing tilt (1.4.1)
mv: cannot remove `/home/benjamin/.bundler/tmp/29173/cache/sprockets-2.2.2.gem': Permission denied
Installing sprockets (2.2.2)
mv: cannot remove `/home/benjamin/.bundler/tmp/29173/cache/actionpack-3.2.13.gem': Permission denied
```

The current user does have sudo level permissions though, which is confusing so I'm not sure how to solve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error doesn't necessarily need to be solved.

Your bundle is installing properly, but it's not able to remove cached gems. It's a pretty harmless error unless you're running way short on hard drive space.

I actually get this same error too. The problem is that my home directory is remotely mounted, so local root doesn't have permission to modify items there. Local root only has global write permissions on *local* directories. I imagine, based on what you describe, that you have the same issue. You could remove the files manually, or you could instruct rvm to install gems in a directory on the local machine.

Comment: you should never use rvm (and installed rubies) with plain `sudo` unless explicitly asked for

Comment: Oops. Right you are -- thanks. I use rbenv, so I forgot about that. Fixed it. Mind removing your downvote?